# Minimum number of $k$-partitions of a set of size $n$ to enumerate all $n \choose k$ combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

Given a set $\mathcal{S}$ of size $n$, let a $k$-partition of $\mathcal{S}$ be a grouping into $k$ disjoint classes $$(S_1 ,S_2,...,S_k)$$

Where the $S_i$ do not necessarily contain the same number of elements.

Let $C(S_1, S_2, ... S_k)$ be the set of combinations which can be made by taking exactly one element of each class, (i.e. $C(S_1, S_2, ... S_k)$ is the Cartesian Product $S_1 \times S_2 \times ...\times S_k$). For a given $(n,k)$, what is the minimum number of k-partitions $N$ such that

$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N} C(S_1^{(i)}, S_2^{(i)}, ...,S_3^{(i)}) = $ All Possible Combinations

Example:

for $n=4$ and $k=2$, $\mathcal{S} = \{1,2,3,4\}$ we can choose:

$$ S^{(1)} = \left\{\left\{ 1, 2\right\}, \left\{ 3, 4\right\}\right\}$$
$$ S^{(2)} = \left\{\left\{ 1, 3\right\}, \left\{ 2, 4\right\}\right\}$$

Then $$C_{1} = \left\{\left\{ 1, 3\right\} ,\left\{ 1, 4\right\},\left\{ 2, 3\right\},\left\{ 2, 4\right\}\right\}$$
$$C_{2} = \left\{\left\{ 1, 2\right\} ,\left\{ 1, 4\right\},\left\{ 2, 3\right\},\left\{ 3, 4\right\}\right\}$$

and $C_1 \cup C_2 =$ All possible combinations and $N=2$.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding $C(S_1, S_2, \ldots S_k)$ to be the Cartesian product $S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_k$?

Comment: Hi @PeterTaylor, Yes, this is correct. It is simply the Cartesian product.

Comment: This is a very interesting (and maybe very hard?) problem.  Where did it come from?

Comment: @antkam Just a thought I had, although I don't think it is without real world application.

Comment: @antkam I formulated another problem based on this one. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427554/minimum-domain-size-to-enumerate-all-n-choose-k-combinations. That one potentially has some interesting implications as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $k=2$ we have $N = \left\lceil \log_2 n\right\rceil$. We can interpret the problem as covering a complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ bipartite graphs, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ bipartite graph contains all the edges between $S_1^{(i)}$ and $S_2^{(i)}$. This was previously asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211745/covering-a-complete-graph-with-as-few-complete-bipartite-subgraphs-as-possible/2211794#2211794). The lower bound $N \ge \log_2 n$ is the same as the general one I'll give below. The upper bound is obtained by letting $S_1^{(i)}$ be the set of all elements of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose binary representation has a $0$ in the $i^{\text{th}}$ position, and letting $S_2^{(i)}$ be the complement. (This takes $\mathcal S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.)

For general $k$, we have $N \ge \log_b \frac n{k-1}$ where $b = \frac{k}{k-1}$. To prove this, we induct on $n$. This is true for $n < k$, since at that point the lower bound we get is nonpositive.

No matter how we choose $(S_1^{(1)}, \dots, S_k^{(1)})$, we still have:

1. Each of the sets $\mathcal S - S_1^{(1)}, \dots, \mathcal S - S_k^{(1)}$ has no $k$-element subsets found in $C(S_1^{(1)}, \dots, S_k^{(1)})$.
2. One of these sets has size at least $\frac{k-1}{k} \cdot n = \frac n b$, because one of the sets $S_i^{(1)}$ has size at most $n/k$.

So passing to a set $\mathcal S' = \mathcal S - S_i^{(1)}$ with both properties, we see that we've obtained none of the $k$-element subsets of $\mathcal S'$ so far. By the inductive hypothesis, we still need $\log_b \frac{n/b}{k-1} = \log_b \frac{n}{k-1} - 1$ more $k$-partitions to see all the $k$-element subsets of $\mathcal S'$; together with the $k$-partition we already used, we need $\log_b \frac{n}{k-1}$ total, as desired.

This gives us the bound $N \ge \log_2 n$ when $k=2$, but I can't think of a matching construction when $k \ge 3$, so I don't know if the bound is tight in general.

---

For an upper bound, we can take a random construction. Choose a random $k$-tuple $(S_1, S_2, \dots, S_k)$ of subsets of $\mathcal S$ by adding each element of $\mathcal S$ to a uniformly random $S_i$. If we do this, then the probability that a given $k$-set is contained in $C(S_1, S_2, \dots, S_k)$ is $\frac{k!}{k^k}$.

If we now take $N$ random $k$-tuples of this form, the probability that a given $k$-set is never covered is $(1 - \frac{k!}{k^k})^N$, so the expected number of uncovered $k$-sets is $\binom nk (1 - \frac{k!}{k^k})^N$. All we need to do is choose $N$ so that this expected value is less than $1$, and we can conclude that with positive probability, the random construction covers all $k$-sets.

Because $1 - x \le e^{-x}$ for all $x$, we have $\binom nk (1 - \frac{k!}{k^k})^N \le \binom nk e^{-N k!/k^k}$, so we can choose $N = \frac{k^k}{k!} \ln \binom nk$. For fixed $k$, this gives a logarithmic upper bound (in $n$) to match the logarithmic lower bound - but the lower bound $\log_b \frac{n}{k-1}$ is roughly $k \ln n$, whereas this upper bound is roughly $k e^k \ln n$, so the constants are pretty far apart.

Comment: "Because one of the sets $S^{(1)}_i$ has size at most $\frac{n}{k}$?" How do I see this?

Comment: There are $k$ disjoint sets that have size $n$ in total.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand, this is obvious... Thanks! Interestingly, we can get closest to this if we always choose "optimal sets" for which the size of $C(S^{(1)}_{1}, S^{(1)}_{2}, ... ,S^{(1)}_{2k})$ is largest. In this case, we want $(k - \text{n mod k})$ of the $S^{(1)}_i$ to be of size $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$ and we want $(\text{n mod k})$ of them to be of size $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil$.

Comment: +1 @MishaLavrov - possible typo?  I think you meant "one of these sets has size at **least** $n/b$ because one of the sets $S^{(1)}_i$ has size at most $n/k$."  I've been thinking of construction since reading your nice answer... but I find it very tough.  So far the only example I have is that for $n=9, k=3$, your bound is $N=4$ and it is achievable as the order $3$ finite affine plane.  However it does not generalize to e.g. order $5$

Comment: @J1996 - First I assume you also had a typo and the last subscript is $k$ not $2k$.  Anyway, intuitively it makes most sense to have $|S^{(j)}_i| = n/k$ or the integers around $n/k$.  The problem is this still leaves a lot of freedom and there is no guarantee that e.g. the 2nd partition can simultaneously efficiently "attack" all the "trouble" sets $\mathcal S - S_i^{(1)}$ left over from the 1st partition.

Comment: Replacing my previous comment: this bound is definitely not tight for large $k$. See my answer for comparison with an alternative bound.

Comment: @antkam I fixed the typo, thanks!

Comment: @MishaLavrov. This is an excellent result for the upper bound! I had a similar random construction but I got stuck on the expectation step. I just have one gripe, which hopefully you can resolve. You say the expected number of uncovered sets is $E({n \choose k} - \lvert \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} C(S_1^{(i)}, ... ,S_k^{(i)}) \lvert) = {n \choose k}\left( 1 - \frac{k!}{k^k}\right)^N$. How do you resolve this with the standard definition of expectation? i.e. $\Sigma xp(x)$

Comment: @J1996 Rather than the standard definition, I use linearity of expectation, writing the number of uncovered sets as $X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_{\binom nk}$, where $X_i$ is $1$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ set is uncovered. The expected value of each $X_i$ is $(1 -\frac{k!}{k^k})^N$, and there are $\binom nk$ of them.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than $N$ I'm going to use the OEIS convention $T(n, k)$ (for *triangle*, I think).

[Misha Lavrov's answer](/a/3403465/5676) gives the bound $$T(n, k) \ge \frac{\log n - \log(k-1)}{\log k - \log(k-1)}$$

Another, easier, lower bound uses the auxiliary function [A152072](http://oeis.org/A152072) which gives the largest possible size of the Cartesian product $S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_k$: then clearly $$T(n, k) \ge \frac{\binom n k}{\textrm{A152072}(n, k)} = \frac{\binom n k}{ \left\lceil n/k \right\rceil^{n \bmod k} \left\lfloor n/k\right\rfloor^{k-n \bmod k}}$$

Neither of these bounds is always better than the other. In fact, we can go further. Note that when $k = n-1$ Misha's bound is $2$, whereas my bound is $\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$ (and this is tight: consider $S_1^{(i)} = \{2i, (2i+1) \bmod n\}$, all other $S_j^{(i)}$ are singletons). On the other hand, when $k=2$ Misha's bound is $\left\lceil \log_2 n\right\rceil$, whereas my bound is $2$. Therefore neither bound is asymptotically tight.

---

Looking at actual figures, we have (starting at $n=1$, $k=1$)

$$\begin{matrix}1 \\
1& 1 \\
1& 2& 1 \\
1& 2& 2& 1 \\
1& 3& 3& 2& 1 \\
1& 3& 3& 3& 2& 1 \\
1& 3& 4& 3& 3& 2& 1 \\
1& 3& 4& 4& 4& 3& 2& 1\end{matrix} \textrm{ vs }\quad \begin{matrix}1 \\
1& 1 \\
1& 2& 1 \\
1& 2& 2& 1 \\
1& 2& 3& 3& 1 \\
1& 2& 3& 4& 3& 1 \\
1& 2& 3& 5& 6& 4& 1 \\
1& 2& 4& 5& 7& 7& 4& 1
\end{matrix}$$
for a combined lower bound of
$$\begin{matrix}1 \\
1& 1 \\
1& 2& 1 \\
1& 2& 2& 1 \\
1& 3& 3& 3& 1 \\
1& 3& 3& 4& 3& 1 \\
1& 3& 4& 5& 6& 4& 1 \\
1& 3& 4& 5& 7& 7& 4& 1\end{matrix}$$

---

By brute force, the actual start of the table should be

$$\begin{matrix}1 \\
1& 1 \\
1& 2& 1 \\
1& 2& 2& 1 \\
1& 3& 3& 3& 1 \\
1& 3& 3& 5& 3& 1 \\
1& 3& 4& 6& 6& 4& 1 \\
1& 3& 4& 6& 8& 8& 4& 1\end{matrix}$$