# A sequence of partitions that splits up every triple

Tags: puzzle, set-partition, extremal-combinatorics, hypergraphs

### The question

We are given a set of size $m$, which we can assume to be the set $[m] = \{1,2,\dots,m\}$.

Say that a sequence $(A_i,B_i,C_i)_{i=1}^k$ *triple-splits* the set $[m]$ if:

- For each $i$, $(A_i, B_i, C_i)$ is a partition of $[m]$: $A_i,B_i,C_i$ are pairwise disjoint subsets of $[m]$, and $A_i \cup B_i \cup C_i = [m]$.
- For every $3$-element subset $\{x,y,z\} \subset [m]$, there is an $i$ such that $A_i \times B_i \times C_i$ contains a permutation of $\{x,y,z\}$. Iin other words, there is an $i$ such that the three elements $x,y,z$ are in different parts of the partition $(A_i, B_i,C_i)$.

What is the smallest $k$, in terms of $m$, for which we can find such a sequence? I am fine with asymptotic answers, and I am interested in both upper bounds (ideally constructive ones) and lower bounds better than $\Omega(\log m)$.

This can be stated in terms of hypergraphs. What is the smallest $k$ for which we can cover the complete $3$-uniform hypergraph on $m$ vertices with $k$ tripartite $3$-uniform hypergraphs?

### Motivation

This is based on my solution to ["I don't want the smallest one, I want the second-smallest one"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101378) on Puzzling.SE. A sequence that triple-splits $[m]$ would give us a solution to the problem of finding the third-smallest element of $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$. Specifically, the formula would be
$$
   \min\Big\{\max\{\min\{x_i : i \in A_1\}, \min\{x_i : i \in B_1\}, \min\{x_i : i \in C_1\}\}, \\
       \qquad\max\{\min\{x_i : i \in A_2\}, \min\{x_i : i \in B_1\},  \min\{x_i : i \in C_2\}\}, \\
       \dots \\
       \qquad\max\{\min\{x_i : i \in A_k\}, \min\{x_i : i \in B_k\}, \min\{x_i : i \in C_k\}\}\Big\}.
$$
Each max is a max of three distinct elements from $\{x_1, \dots, x_m\}$, so each max is at least the third-smallest element. On the other hand, if the sequence triple-splits $[m]$, and $x_a,x_b,x_c$ are the three smallest elements, then there has to be some $i$ for which $A_i, B_i, C_i$ each contain one of $a,b,c$. For that $i$, the max we'll get will be $\max\{x_a,x_b,x_c\}$: exactly the third-smallest element.

Comment: For $m \in \{1,\dots,10\}$, the smallest such $k$ are $0,0,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5$.

Comment: Trivial upper bound: $\binom{m}{3}$

Comment: For $m$ divisible by $3$, a lower bound is $\lceil \binom{m}{3}/(m/3)^3 \rceil$ because each partition covers at most $(m/3)^3$ of the $\binom{m}{3}$ triples.  By monotonicity of the smallest $k$, this lower bound is also valid for $m+1$ and $m+2$.

Comment: This lower bound is unfortunately constant. I mentioned $\Omega(\log m)$ in the question, because that's a lower bound for the [pair version of the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211745), which I think should carry over.

Comment: And now that I looked at that question, I see that this question has already been asked... in fact, I answered it...

Comment: A slightly less trivial upper bound is $\binom{m}{2}$, obtained by considering $\{\{i\},\{j\},[m]\setminus \{i,j\}\}$ for each $i < j$