# Set Problem:find the minimum number of d

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, permutations

$\Omega =\left \{1,2,3\dots,n\right\}$,$(k<n)$,$\Gamma$ is the set of the k-subsets of $\Omega$. Let us fix d partitions $(G^{(i)})_{1,2\dots,d}$ of $\Omega$ where each $(G^{(i)}$ is a partition in $k$ non-empty subsets.We define $\Gamma_{(i)}$ as the cartesian product $G_1^{(i)}\times G_2^{(i)}\times G_3^{(i)}\dots\times G_k^{(i)}$,our goal is to find the minimal $d$  such that we can find $d$  partitions$(G^{(i)})_{1,2\dots,d}$ of $\Omega$ such that the union $\cup\Gamma _{(i)}=\Gamma$ (the $\Gamma_{(i)} $ cover $\Gamma$).

Taking $k=4$ and $n=8$ as an example,
$G^{i}_{1}=(1,2) ,G^{i}_{2}=(3,4) ,G^{i}_{3}=(5,6), G^{i}_{4}=(7,8)$.
A corresponding set can be obtained:
$\Gamma _{(i)}=\left \{ \left \{ 1,3,5,7 \right \} ,\left \{1,3,5,8 \right\},\left \{2,3,5,7 \right\},\dots, \left \{2,4,6,8 \right\} \right \}$,
$\Gamma=\Gamma\setminus  \Gamma _{(i)}$.

$k=2 $ and $n=4$ are used as an example.$\Gamma=\left \{ \left \{ 1,2 \right \},\left \{ 1,3 \right \},\left \{ 1,4 \right \}, \left \{ 2,3 \right \} ,\left \{ 2,4 \right \},\left \{ 3,4 \right \}\right \}$
(1) In the first division,$ G^{1}_1=(2, 3),G^{1}_2=(1, 4)$;so the $\Gamma _{(1)}=\left \{ \left \{ 1,2 \right \},\left \{ 1,3 \right \},\left \{ 2,4 \right \}, \left \{ 3,4 \right \} \right \}$.
(For those subsets that have appeared in the previous division, they will no longer be used),the $\Gamma=\Gamma\setminus  \Gamma _{(1)}=\left \{\left \{ 1,4 \right \}, \left \{ 2,3 \right \} \right \}$.
(2) the second division,  $ G^{2}_1=(1, 2), G^{2}_2=(3, 4)$,the $\Gamma _{(2)}=\left \{ \left \{ 2,3 \right \},\left \{ 1,4 \right \} \right \}$,the $\Gamma=\Gamma\setminus  \Gamma _{(2)}= \phi$.

Through the above two divisions, we can obtain two subsets $\Gamma_{(1)}$,$\Gamma_{(2)}$,which are the results of the division of the $\Gamma$ and the minimal $d=2$.
So how to find the minimal $d$?

Comment: "Group" in relation to mathematics means something very specific, a certain structure in abstract algebra. This is not what you mean, so I suggest you edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit convoluted and not very standard. Can I reformulate your problem as something like this: $\Gamma$ is the set of the $k$-subsets of $\Omega$. Let us fix $d$ partitions $(G^{(i)})_{i=1...d}$ of $\Omega$ where each $G^{(i)}$ is a partition in $k$ non-empty subsets. We define $\Gamma_{(i)}$ as the cartesian product $G^{(i)}_1 \times G^{(i)}_2 \times ... \times G^{(i)}_k$. 
We want to find the minimal $d$ such that we can find $d$ partitions $(G^{(i)})_{i=1...d}$ of $\Omega$ such that the union $\bigcup \Gamma_{(i)} = \Gamma$ (the $\Gamma_{(i)}$ cover $\Gamma$).

Comment: Here the $\Gama_{(i)}$ are not necessarily disjoint, but this should not change the problem.

Comment: @caduk Thank you,I've updated the phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known in the literature as perfect $k$-hashing. It is generally formulated as follows:

Find the smallest $d$ such that we can find $n$ vectors in $\{1...k\}^d$ such that for every subset of $k$ vectors, we can find a coordinate where these are all different.

Here, each value in $\Omega$ is associated with a vector. The $i$-th value of the vector corresponds to the position of the value in the partition $G^{(i)}$.

For $k=2$, the problem is equivalent to the bipartite dimension of the complete graph, which is known to be $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$ (see [Covering a complete graph with as few complete bipartite subgraphs as possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211745/covering-a-complete-graph-with-as-few-complete-bipartite-subgraphs-as-possible))

For the other $k$, the problem is still open.

For $k=3$, the problem is known as the trifference problem. The best bounds as of now are [1, 2]:
$$\frac{\log(n/c)}{\log(3/2)} \approx 1.71\log_2(n/c)\leq d \leq 4\frac{\log(n)}{\log(9/5)} \approx 4.72\log_2(n)$$
Where $c$ is a constant that can be $2$, or $1.0825$ for $n\geq 14$

For other $k$, assuming $n\gg k$, we have the following asymptotic bounds [1]:
$$\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!}\log_2(n) \leq d \leq \frac{k\log_2(n)}{\log_2(1-k!/k^k)}$$

For some small $k$, we know slightly better constants, but not much better.

When $k$ is not small in comparison to $n$, the asymptotics are really different, but I could not manage to find references.

[1]: *Fredman, Michael L.; Komlos, Janos*, [**On the size of separating systems and families of perfect hash functions**](https://doi.org/10.1137/0605009), SIAM J. Algebraic Discrete Methods 5, 61-68 (1984). [ZBL0525.68037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0525.68037).

[2]: *Körner, J.; Marton, K*, [**New bounds for perfect hashing via information theory**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(88)80048-9), Eur. J. Comb. 9, No. 6, 523-530 (1988). [ZBL0676.68007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0676.68007).

Comment: So I can also get the subset details of each division at the same time?

Comment: @CelesteTang The bounds are based on probabilistic arguments, so it is not clear if there is a constructive algorithm to achieve the lower bound